# How can redirect outputs from a sequence of commands to stdout and to a file in Tcl?

Tags: file, io, tcl

Instead of doing something like below, I am looking for an elegant way to redirect outputs from a sequence of commands to stdout and to a file simultaneously in Tcl if possible.

e.g. two step method

```
proc foo {} { return "bar" }
puts "I call foo"
foo

set i_f [open myfile w]
puts $i_f "I call foo"
exec echo [foo] >> myfile
```

If I write first and then print the contents of that file, it would take a bit more time to read and print the contents out, so I am wondering if there is an elegant method to simultaneously write to two channels (to an opened file for writing and to stdout).

Moreover, I would like to know if it is possible to change the current stdout to another channel temporarily and then change the stdout back to the original stdout.

There are multiple Tcl proc calls where all of them are outputting to stdout (either through plain puts or through Tcllib's report package).

Instead of reviewing and changing the contents of each Tcl procs, I would like to instead output them to another channel for writing to a file and then change the stdout to the original stdout.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_transform/observe.md

Answer (score 3):

You may create a new puts command to replace the original puts. In the new command, puts message to stdout and a file.

```
rename puts _puts  ;# Replace Tcl build-in puts
set chan_log [open log_file w]
# Create a new puts command
proc ::puts { msg } {
  ::_puts $msg
  ::_puts $::chan_log $msg
}

puts "Hello, world!"
close $chan_log
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on any Unix, you can use the `dup` command from TclX.

```
package require Tclx

# Redirect stdout to a file
set alternate [open /some/place/you-want-to/capture.to w+]
set saved [dup stdout]
dup $alternate stdout

try {
    # Do your code here
} finally {
    # Restore stdout to wherever it was before
    dup $saved stdout
    close $saved
}

# Now you can use [seek $alternate 0] and read the data written
```

You are *recommended* to use `try`/`finally` when doing manipulation of `stdout` (or any other standard channel) so that you ensure it is restored even in the event of an error. This prevents all sorts of confusing situations.

Comment: The code apparently also works on Windows, but will be subject to more caveats due to complexities in the native I/O layer. On Unix, you can redirect to other channel types too, so long as they have a direct native handle.